# VSC compile error cant find find header file

Tags: compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-c++

Arduino 1.8.19
VSC 1.75.1

Updated VSC last night and now I have

```
D:\Arduino\Projects\WsLogger\WsLogger2\WsLogger2.ino:24:27: fatal error: ATDateandTime.h: No such file or directory
```

There are a number of other headers that also exhibit this problem.  If you put the full path to the user library (D:\Arduino\Projects\libraries) into the #include using double quotes then it works ok (but that means editing library header files as well so not a fix).

If you left click on the offending include and select "go to Definition" it goes there (no sqiggles).

It looks like there is a setting somewhere in VSC that is included in the make process so that the compiler has the path to the user libraries.  I have to admit to not knowing how the make works (any pointers to that gratefully received).

Any ideas?

Thanks

---

WsLogger2.ino with offending lines marked "-->"

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <time.h>     // time() ctime()
#include <sys/time.h> // struct timeval
#include <sntp.h>     // sntp_servermode_dhcp()
#include "TZ.h"
#include "ISSFlash.h"
#include "Menu.h"
#include <SD.h>
#include "DavisServer.h"
#include "Defs.h"
#include <Ticker.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "DavisISSLib.h"
--> #include <ATDateandTime.h>
--> #include <DavisRFM69.h> // From https://github.com/dekay/DavisRFM69
--> #include <AT_gen_Utils.h>
```

c_cpp_properties.json - These paths are correct and the headers are all in the library

```
"D:\\Arduino\\Projects\\libraries\\ATDateandTime",
"D:\\Arduino\\Projects\\libraries\\DavisRFM69-master",
"D:\\Arduino\\Projects\\libraries\\AT_gen_Utils",
"D:\\Arduino\\Projects\\libraries\\TZ",
```

Comment: c_cpp_properties.json is for intellisense. You should add those paths to the compiler -I args in tasks.json.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

When I installed the Arduino app it created (on the c: drive) all the necessary directories including projects\libraries, this libraries directory was empty.  I prefer not to work on the boot drive instead using D:\Arduino\Project\libraries which is where all my libraries are kept.  The directory change setting is in the Arduino app, File->Preferences->Settings->Sketchbook location. The fix was to copy the libraries from the d drive to the c drive.  Once the app was compiled once it seemed not to look at the c libraries again.  Something has changed within VSC/MS VSU Arduino plugin.